# MS-SIPAE <-> SSPI: MakeSignature is 'GSS_GetMIC’?

Tags: sspi

I have the following question about  Windows SSPI. I have made an Win32 app that has to authorize with a  server: using protocol MS-SIPAE in NTLM mode. The app uses SSPI. 
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc431510.aspx. about the MS-SIPAE.  There is the following step there (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd946897.aspx): “The protocol client uses an authentication protocol GSS_GetMIC() call, as specified in [MS-NLMP] section 3.1.4 for NTLM, and in [RFC2743] section 2.3.1 for Kerberos, to generate a signature token for the buffer constructed in the preceding step 2 using the authentication protocol context stored in the SA. ”

The question is: what exactly corresponds to the  abstract “GSS_GetMIC” in SSPI API? In SSPI I have found a function named MakeSignature – seems this is what I need. Also an MSDN article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995331.aspx seems to confirm this. Can someone confirm this conclusion (I do not want rely on the ‘seems’ )?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, GSS_GetMic is corresponding to MakeSignature.  I have implemented similar thing.  See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995352.aspx) for the full description on the details of SSPI interoperability with GSSAPI.